# Print the sum of the list of numbers. If the list is empty zero is printed also the element 7 and the element next to it won’t contribute to the sum

Tags: python-3.x

I tried solving this way but didn't work. This is a question from geeksforgeeks

```
arr = [1,  3, 4, 4, 7, 7]
def check(arr):
    sums = sum(arr)
    if arr == []:
       sums = 0
    else:
       for i in range(len(arr)-1):
            if arr[i] == 7:
               sums = sums-arr[i]-arr[i+1]
   
            else:
               sums = sums
    return sums
```

Comment: It works for me (`check(arr)` returns `12`). What is your issue? It won't work for some edge cases, though (such as `7, 7, x` will subtract `7` three times instead of two).

Comment: *"next to it"*: does that mean at the right only?

Comment: What is the expected answer for the example? Do you have a link to the code challenge?

Comment: @trincot please find the link to the question: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/contest/fork-python-module-5/problems

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat vague in defining what "next to it" is, I assumed it's the succeeding element.
So I made a solution with a constraint that literal `7` and number subsequent to `7` are ignored in the summation of the sequence

```py
def check(seq):
    return sum(n for i, n in enumerate(seq) if n != 7 and seq[i - (i != 0)] != 7)
```

Checks that I did on the solution to match the requirements :

```py
assert check([]) == 0, "Empty case"
assert check([1, 7, 8, 1]) == 2, "Exclude 7 and the number next to (8 is ignored) it"
assert check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]) == 21, "Exclude 7"
assert check([7, 10]) == 0, "7 and 10 are ignored"
```

If you have an link to the original code challenge then posting it here would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
def realSum(mylist):
    l1=0
    v=[]
    if len(mylist)>0:
        for i in range(len(mylist)):
            if mylist[i]==7:
               if i not in v or v==[]:
                  if i!=len(mylist)-1:
                    v.append(i)
                    v.append(i+1)
                  else:
                    v.append(i)
       for i in range(len(mylist)):
          if i not in v:
             l1+=mylist[i]
       return l1
   else:
       return 0
```